# alternative to @XmlSeeAlso

Tags: java, jaxb

```
abstract Class A{

}


Class B extends A{

}


@XmlRootElement
Class C {
   @XmlElement(name = "tobeserialized")
   A tobeserialized;
}


Class D{
 public void marshal(){
 C all = getData();
 JAXB.marshal(all, new File("saved.xml");

  }
```

}

for JAXB to know that class B is a subclass of class A, i would need to put a @XmlSeeAlso(value = {B.class}) on Class A.  We have around 50 subclasses of A.

But the project dependency is such that Class A lies in a package which cannot access Class B. So I cannot put the annotation on Class A.

what can be the alternatives to look at, so that JAXB can serialize the subclasses of Class A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation isn't required when mapping an inheritance relationship, but that is when it is most often used.  The role of `@XmlSeeAlso` is to tell JAXB to pull in and produce metadata for classes that can't be inferred from traversing the class.

In your example if you created the `JAXBContext` on just the `C` class (`JAXBContext.newInstance(C.class)`) then the `A` class would also be processed due to the `tobeserialized` field, but `B` wouldn't because there isn't a mechanism in Java to find subclasses. You could solve this by putting `@XmlSeeAlso(B.class)` on `A` or by including the subclasses in the classes used to bootstrap the `JAXBContext`:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(B.class, C.class);
```

Comment: @XmlSeeAlso gives a one time declaration. I edited my question and you could see how easy was it for me to marshal, without knowing the subclasses while marshalling. This wuld mean I would have to initialize the JAXBContext with all my 50 subclasses. And Class C contains other objects also, I would have to declare them also.

Comment: @tak - It doesn't need to be an either or situation.  You can use `@XmlSeeAlso` for all the visible classes and pass the others in when creating `JAXBContext`.  Alternatively you coul reference them with an `@XmlSeeAlso` on a class outside the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: Also created a utils class that does all the initializes JAXB with all the subclasses. This really makes my code as easy as it was before.

Answer (score 0):

Been a long time for me, but you may try to add `@XmlTransient` on class A and `@XmlType` on class B.

Or `@XmlTransient` on classes A and B (since they're abstract) and add `@XmlType` to concrete subclasses.

Comment: sorry I had put abstract on class B but it isn't. I have edited my question now..

Comment: `@XmlTransient` is added to a class to have it ignored from an inheritance hierarchy:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/ignoring-inheritance-with-xmltransient.html